# Bash: variable from file match regex

Tags: bash

My script goes as follow:

1. Search for all the isos available under some path
2. Compare the isos names to a list in a file
3. Return only the matches

To abreviate, the code is:

```
isos_found=() # here we save the isos
isos_search=<find isos>
mapfile -t supported_isos < supported_systems # see below
for iso in "${isos_search[@]}" ; do
  [[ "${supported_isos[@]}" =~ "$(basename "$iso")"  ]] && isos_found+=("$iso")
done
```

Where `supported_systems` is a file with the contents:

```
clonezilla-live-2.6.1-25-amd64.iso
debian-live-10.0.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso
linuxmint-19.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso
linuxmint-19.1-xfce-32bit.iso
lubuntu-18.04-alternate-amd64.iso
```

Now I would like that the file `supported_systems` had the content like this:

```
clonezilla*
debian*
linuxmint*
lubuntu*
```

So I have to match only the name of the distro without harcoding every version/release.

Using code similar to the one above (`"${supported_isos[@]}" =~ "$(basename "$iso")"`) is this possible? If not, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `supported_systems` file contains *prefix strings* (not patterns) like

```
clonezilla
debian
linuxmint
lubuntu
```

Then you could simply read these string and use them in a file glob match instead of first trying to find all ISO files and then manually go through an see whether they match some pattern.

```bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar

isos=()
while IFS= read -r prefix; do
        isos+=( ./**/"$prefix"-*.iso )
done <supported_systems

printf '%s\n' "${isos[@]}"
```

If you do want to find all ISO files first and then go through them to find the ones that match any of the prefixes, then you could use

```bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar

isos=( ./**/*.iso )
while IFS= read -r prefix; do
        for iso in "${isos[@]}"; do
                if [[ $iso =~ /"$prefix"-[^/]*$ ]]; then
                        matched_isos+=( "$iso" )
                fi
        done
done <supported_systems

printf '%s\n' "${matched_isos[@]}"
```

Here, the regular expression `/"$prefix"-[^/]*$` would match any base name that starts with a given `$prefix` (followed by `-`).